# How do I specify method parameter in @route in play framework?

Tags: javascript, playframework, routes

I have the following definition in conf/routes:

```
GET     /amethod/*path                controllers.Application.amethod(path: String)
```

and the following in Application.java:

```
public static WebSocket<String> amethod(String path){
....
}
```

but how do I specify the URL in JavaScript with e.g. path = "someValue"?

I tried e.g.:

```
new WS("@routes.Application.amethod(\"someValue\").webSocketURL(request)")
new WS("@routes.Application.amethod('someValue').webSocketURL(request)")
```

but it only works with path = null:

```
new WS("@routes.Application.amethod(null).webSocketURL(request)")
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way (and also recommended way) to generate URLs to be used at JavaScript code is using [JavaScript Routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting). Unfortunately, there is no documentation for the Java version, at least not in 2.4.x documentation (this was [solved for version 2.5](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.0-RC2/JavaJavascriptRouter)).

Here is what you have to do.

#### JavaScript routes endpoint

Declare an action in some controller exposing your Javascript routes:

```
public static Result javascripts() {
  response().setContentType("text/javascript");
  return ok(
    Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
      // Routes
      controllers.routes.javascript.Application.aMethod(),
      controllers.routes.javascript.Application.anotherMethod()
    )
  );
}
```

Then, have a route to the action above:

```
GET    /assets/javascripts/routes.js    controllers.Application.javascripts()
```

Or any other path you want, like:

```
GET    /assets/potatoes.js    controllers.Application.javascripts()
```

And add this JavaScript to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.javascripts()"></script>
```

And that is it. Now, lets see how to use the JavaScript routes.

#### Using the JavaScript routes:

The advantage here is that you can use the JavaScript router both in your views and also in other `.js` files. To do so, at your Javascript code, do something like this:

```
 var webSocketUrl = jsRoutes.controllers.Application.aMethod("/some/parameter").webSocketURL()
 var myWs = new WS(webSocketUrl)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering - two questions: 
1) The action in the controller does not recognize aMethod() or anotherMethod(), even though I have them in Application.java?
2) routes.js should be a file "routes.scala.js" under views? Currently I only have a "routes" file under conf?

Comment: 1) Do you mean, there is a compiler error when running or your IDE does not recognize them? Sometimes, IDEs have problem to recognize generated sources. 2) You don't need to create routes.js files anywhere, Play will do that for you. I've added another example to illustrate that.

Comment: 1) It's a compile error "error: cannot find symbol". 
2) So Play creates a routes/potatoes.js file?
NB: I had to make the method in the controller static to avoid the error "value javascripts is not a member of object controllers.Application".

Comment: 1) Where are you seeing this error? 2) Yes. 3) Change my example to use the `static` keyword too. ;-)

Comment: 1) In the command prompt where I started the server with "activator run" after I have refreshed the page in a browser. The error is displayed in the browser as well.

Comment: Could you please create a [gist](https://gist.github.com) with the relevant bits (controllers, routes and views) and share it here?